# How to change comments data with onchange function in addfield in magento

Tags: magento

I created custom module and now from admin side on edit form i added extra field select type.
I want to change comments with onchange function for this specific field.See below my code.

```
$eventElem = $fieldset->addField('banner_type', 'select', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('multibanners')->__('Banner Style'),
                'required'  => false,
                'onchange' => 'checkSelectedItem(this.value)',
                'name'      => 'banner_type',
                'values'    => array(
                   array(
                        'value'     => 'Banner 1',
                        'label'     => 'AnySlider',      
                   ),
                   array(
                       'value'     => 'Banner 2',
                       'label'     => 'Content Slider',         
                 ),
              ));
$eventElem->setAfterElementHtml("<script type=\"text/javascript\">function checkSelectedItem(selectElement){}</script>");
```

This is my code i alert the value and i got my value but it cannot show it in comments area .Did someone one know how to fix it ?

Thanks

Comment: What is comments, is it a text area, addField note.. etc? Could you also add the code for comment.

Comment: comments are just information about the field like field note.for normal comments field we can show comments by  'after_element_html' => '<small>Comments</small>' , but in my one i want to show it dynamically so i use $eventElem->setAfterElementHtml() methode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will update the comment (onchange) with the current selected option

```
$fieldset->addField('banner_type', 'select', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('multibanners')->__('Banner Style'),
        'required'  => false,
        'onchange' => 'checkSelectedItem(this.value)',
        'name'      => 'banner_type',
        'values'    => array(
           array(
                'value'     => 'Banner 1',
                'label'     => 'AnySlider',      
           ),
           array(
               'value'     => 'Banner 2',
               'label'     => 'Content Slider',         
           ),
        )
 ))->setAfterElementHtml("<small id='banner_type_comment'>Comments</small>
                         <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                            function checkSelectedItem(selectElement){ 
                               $('banner_type_comment').update($('banner_type')[$('banner_type').selectedIndex].text);
                            }
                         </script>");
```